# How to get a list of sites where I have used a yahoo openid?

Tags: openid, yahoo

I have been using my flickr url as my openid on a number of sites. Since I found out that my google profile can also serve as my openid I was thinking of changing all my registrations from flickr to google.

I was surprised to know that yahoo does not provide a list of websites with whom it has shared my information. Is there a way to find this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not unless Yahoo exposes that information.

It is possible for an OpenID provider to do this, as they do know of the authentications, but if Yahoo doesn't expose it, then .. well, that's that.

Comment: actually now they have provided an option. go to your yahoo account information and click in manage apps and website connections. very handy. :)